# Using multi-sampling creates artifacts along mesh edges (DirectX, C#)

Tags: c#, directx, artifacts, multisampling

I'm rendering a mesh in a visual c#, using directx. When turning on anti-aliasing, I got following artifacts along the edges on mesh (see image). Artifacts shows only on edges turned toward the camera and they shows on every mesh I load. I'm using DirectX 9.0 libraries and the problem is present only on my Windows 10 desktop. I use also Windows XP desktop for testing and mesh is displayed correctly there. Also, the level of multisampling seems not to influence the problem (but the problem disappear when mutisampling is set to none)

Here is the initialization of parameters:

```
PresentParameters presentParameters = new PresentParameters();
presentParameters.BackBufferFormat = Format.Unknown;
presentParameters.Windowed = true;
presentParameters.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
presentParameters.AutoDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.D24X8;
presentParameters.MultiSample = MultiSampleType.FourSamples;
presentParameters.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
```

I'm grateful for any advice.

Here is the mesh with the edges:

[image: mesh with the edges]

Answer (score 0):

The latest windows ( 8 and + ) have seen major changes to swap chains and presentation. Newer direct-x API does not even authorize multisampled swap chains.

You may or may not do something weird here but it is hard to diagnoze without more details. I recommend to you to not create a multisampled swap chain buta regular one, create the multisampled surface separately (color + depth) and resolve the color to your backbuffer. It should solve your problem.

Comment: i'm quite new to this and i'm mot sure if i get it right. you suggest i copy a back buffer to a surface, run some mask on it (such as roberts) to create antialiasing effect and than copy it back to  back buffer? or is there some method that can already do this?

Comment: No, nothing like that, just turn off autodepth and multisampling at swapchain creation, create new color and dept  surface for your render, then call resolve from these surface to your backbuffer.

Comment: you are correct, that should solve the problem from what i have read about it, but i have problems to find examples on how to use surfaces in c# and i'm becoming frustrated from all the try/error approach. if you can please write me a source code in c# how to do this, i would be very appreciative. as this is part of my work project, i'm willing to even donate $20 to you paypal if the solution will work.

Comment: @lakersk I am sorry, but as an employee engineer, i make >$60/h, a freelance job is easily double or triple and what you ask would take at least a few hours ! If you have trouble, post the relevant portion of code, and i will be glad to help, but i can't do it all for you.

Comment: ok, than. i though i would be 4-5 lines of code involving CreateRenderTarget and SetRenderTarget commands and should not take more than 5 minutes. if it is that complex, i understand. thanks for help anyway.